# The percentage equivalent of my REM value in css comes out bigger in size than the actual REM value

Tags: css, percentage

---

I was using REM values for my website and now I want to change them to their percentage equivalent but they just come out very much bigger than their actual size. I calculated the percentage equivalent of the REM using an online REM to % calculator.

Comment: Without some [reprex] there's little ppl can do to help. Be aware though, that `font-size` with percentages are relative to their (cascaded) parent and **not** necessarily relative to `:root/html`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.